# According to Full Preterism, what do Thunders mean?

Tags: exegesis, eschatology, revelation, preterism

In the 10th chapter of the Revelation of John the Theologian, says:

> Rev 10:4 And when the seven thunders uttered with their voices, I was about to write; but heard a voice from heaven saying to me: hide what the seven thunders have said, and do not write this.

According to Full Preterism, what do Thunders mean?